# Can't get Postman to successfully authenticate against Entra/Azure AD on Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, postman

I setup my Azure Function to authenticate against my own tenant like so...
[image: picture of function auth]

The app registration for the resource has an api exposed like this
[image: scope api]

After doing so if I hit it in browser, as myself it asks me to authenticate and then works.  Great!   I'm now trying to hit this in Postman and I get a 401 no matter what I do.

postman is logging in as its own service principal (1ec5483f-8eb9-4851-af81-ff89eb3e25ad)
and API permissions are set like this
[image: postman api permissions]

I then set up an OATH 2 token in POSTMAN client - and it gets one which seems valid
[image: postman set up]

I obviously blanked out secret deliberately.  Scope is set to api://31f5b60c-5de3-4135-85ec-08edfbce042e/General.Read.  Access Token URL = https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant/oauth2/v2.0/authorize.  Token URL = https://login.microsoftonline.com/my tenant/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

The token decrypted looks like this:

```
{
  "aud": "api://31f5b60c-5de3-4135-85ec-08edfbce042e",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/mytenant/",
  "iat": 1695814282,
  "nbf": 1695814282,
  "exp": 1695818220,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "ATQAy/8UAAAAS8sRzKTgrNlGhofLEKYO7xweUqSUmLrqQWFN8i0o/qsoeBqavqK7oQXJt19EOeBk",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "1ec5483f-8eb9-4851-af81-ff89eb3e25ad",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "XXX",
  "given_name": "XXX",
  "ipaddr": "XXX",
  "name": "XXX",
  "oid": "1c11db5e-dc85-4c4b-882e-b8dd40206255",
  "onprem_sid": "S-1-5-21-57989841-1450960922-725345543-4904",
  "rh": "0.ARcAdKQVoiCS8E-TJSBRMiYmswy29THjXTVBhewI7fvOBC4XACo.",
  "roles": [
    "Trigger.Function"
  ],
  "scp": "General.Read",
  "sub": "q7tSjCuR5mf56ekcpYI4xEZ6Kdo_zfXkT2oBYEsyohQ",
  "tid": "a215a474-9220-4ff0-9325-2051322626b3",
  "unique_name": "XXX@XXX.com",
  "upn": "XXX@XXX.com",
  "uti": "0W4WOPhO406S8ahy4GkmAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Again this eyeballs right to me.  But when I call

[image: postman get request]

Its ALWAYS 401.   Where am I going wrong?

here is a picture of the function url... no code
[image: No code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Function app and enabled Authentication** like below:

[image]

In Azure AD Application an API is Exposed:

[image]

Added API permissions:

[image]

Now, I tried to generate **access token** and authenticate Function app by using below parameters:

```json
GET https://testrukfunctapp1.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

Callback URL : RedirectURL
Auth URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
ClientID : ClientID
Client Secret : ***
Scope : api://xxx/user_impersonation
```

**I got the same error (401 Unauthorized) like below:**

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make sure to pass **`x-functions-key`** header:

[image]

The **`x-functions-key`** value is the code value in the function URL:

[image]

After passing the header, **I am able to authenticate the Function app successfully** using access token like below:

```json
GET https://testrukfunctapp1.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

x-functions-key : FunctionURLCodeValue
Content-Type : application/json
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have a code value in my function url....  where is that coming from?  my function is dirt simple anonymous.  

const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('testHttp1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

        return { body: `Hello, ${name}!` };
    }
});

Comment: Can you go to your Function App -> Select your function -> Click on Get Function URL -> Copy the Function URL

Comment: https://unlinked-secure-we-app-api.azurewebsites.net/api/testHttp1?  is what this gives me.... is there a way to turn on the code?

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot ?

Comment: Using 2.0....  will add picture above

Comment: After the question mark in the function URL there is no code as updated in my answer?

Comment: And did you manually exposed the API in app registration or was it exposed automatically after creating app registration in function app?

Comment: no code after the ? at all - that's end of the the box.  I added the exposed API manually

Comment: When I selected the create new app registration in the function app the expose api was created automatically. Hence you are getting 401 error

Comment: Starting from scratch and letting portal make the id worked!  thanks