I can't authenticate a call to an Azure function. I tried a Function Key and an OAuth 2.0 with a client secret... Neither work
My question relates to Azure functions. The ultimate goal is to have a separate app call out to this function. I have a C# MVC app and there's one really strange piece of logic that has to be performed on one page of my MVC app. Because of the weird need for one-of-a-kind libraries that are only written in JavaScript, I have to put this logic into a separate function to be triggered via HTTP request. My MVC app will send the payload to the Azure function, processes the data, and send it back to the MVC page.
So I'm creating the Azure function separately and testing it in Postman. I made a dummy Azure function that receives some data, modifies it slightly, and sends back the data via an HTTP response.
I wrote the Azure function, deployed it to a resource group via this command with sensitive data omitted for privacy:
az functionapp create --resource-group RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME_CREATED_HERE 
   --consumption-plan-location eastus --runtime node 
   --name APP_NAME_CREATED_HERE
   --storage-account STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME_CREATED_HERE

I tested it via Postman, and everything worked perfectly. The function ran as expected, received my input, and spit out the corresponding data in its response. The difficult part is the authentication. I tried to add authentication and it completely broke. It only 401 errors now.
Here is how I went about creating the authentication:
I made an app registration and put my Azure function in this app registration.

This App Registration space has 2 client secrets (one was auto-generated and one I made), and I set up a web redirect URI for OAuth 2.0.
This is the Function's overview display page:

This is the function's authentication page:

You can't see it in the picture but the "Identity Provider" is the same as the "App Registration" that I created.
When I click "Edit" on the Identity Provider listed, it brings me here:

I tried to use Postman to generate a bearer authentication token via OAuth 2.0 and then use that token to hit the API.

That worked to generate a token but I still got a 401 error when I tried to actually use that generated token to hit the function. I tried this with both the client secret that I created and "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET," both create Bearer tokens, but the following requests with each token gave me 401 errors.
I tried the post request with no auth and put the "x-functions-key" header in the post request with the corresponding "default" function key shown here:

This also gave me a 401. Does anyone see what the problem is? Or maybe I'm going about this all wrong? I just want to create an HTTP request API that performs a simple JavaScript function and gives me the result. It needs to be authenticated in a way that only my MVC app's backend that never touches a browser can hit it, so it's okay if the function needs some kind of hard-coded secret to run.


I have created a default Http triggered JavaScript function for testing purpose and deployed to NodeJS function app then I enabled Authentication alike you as shown below and chose all the default selected options while creating it.



Then I added a Web platform in the registered app and set the redirect URIs, one for directly accessing the function in browser (https://{functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback) and other one is for Postman authentication (https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback).



I have added given details in postman to generate the token.



Token got generated successfully and I am able to invoke the function in postman.


I replicated your steps and I still got a 401 error. The only thing different between your workflow and mine is that my scope doesn't end in /.default. When I created the scope I ended it with a custom name instead of /.default.

can you try the scope in my way once to check if it works for you?

I tried but I got this in Postman https://imgur.com/a/w5LwoTl . When I clicked the "View Console" button it showed Error: invalid_request.

Have you added all the correct data needed for token? Are you using Auth type as OAuth 2.0? Please verify all the  fields and make sure you have added the postman url as Redirect URI in the registered app.

Yes, all of the fields are definitely correct. Where are you getting scope? Maybe that's where I'm going wrong. I had to create my own scope because there was no scopes listed https://imgur.com/a/SKGmjs0 . That scope in the pic was manually created by me. I gave it a custom name, so I don't have a /.default scope. I also created a custom App Role to run the function https://imgur.com/a/PFRXyuw . and I added it to API Permissions https://imgur.com/a/hKJTxRd . Do you see the problem yet?

I am using scope as client id/.default. Try to use this

I tried remember. Postman gave me Error: invalid_request when I tried to generate the token.

Can you please refer this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187333/cant-get-postman-to-successfully-authenticate-against-entra-azure-ad-on-azure-f/77187924#77187924

@ChristianOConnor Does this works for you?

No, I was never able to get it working. I just got rid of all authentication through "App Registration" and "Identity Platform" widgets in Azure and changed authLevel: 'anonymous', to authLevel: 'function', Now the authentication happens after the function is called and I use the default key to successfully call the function. So I didn't really fix the problem, I gave up and did something else.

@ChristianOConnor authLevel is related to function only but you are generating token incorrectly. If you will follow all the steps given in the answer correctly and create an app from the scratch then you might get it working

I think using an Identity Provider was the wrong approach altogether. I said in my question that I wanted to run this function from the backend of an MVC app. I realized that Microsoft Identity Provider tries to sign in with a Microsoft account right? I don’t want that here. I just need something to make it so only my MVC backend can access the function.

Yes, it will sign in to Microsoft account if you are using Authentication functionality available in Function App. You can simply change the AuthLevel to Function or Admin and pass the code while invoking the function

Interesting, so do you think it would be better for security if I use Microsoft Identity Provider for authentication, even though this function will solely be called from the backend of a separate MVC app?

You can but I believe in your scenario it's better to use only function apps authLevel
